# Fluent NHibernate: How to have a one-to-many reference in both directions?

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

We have *Users* on our system and *Persons*.  There are many Persons for each User.  But when a user logs on, we need to look up his primary Person record to fill in his name, address, phone, etc.

```
public class Person
{
    /// <summary>Every Person belongs to a user.</summary>
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }
    public virtual string LastName { get; set; }
    public virtual string Address { get; set; }
    public virtual string Phone { get; set; }
    // More methods & Properties
}

public class User : Entity
{
    public virtual string Username { get; set; }
    public virtual string Password { get; set; }
    /// <summary>Every User has a primary person record.</summary>
    public virtual Person PrimaryPerson { get; set; }
    // More methods & Properties
}
```

How does the class map look for this without a circular reference?

Comment: So a User has a 1 to many relationship with Person, and User has a Primary Person.?

Comment: That is correct, Phil.  A single User will have many Persons.  But only one of those Persons is the PrimaryPerson.

Comment: Probably I'm missing something but why can't you just have `References(x => x.User)` on `PersonMap` and `References(x => x.PrimaryPerson)` on `UserMap`? NHibernate will basically see these are seperate one-to-many relationships (as `User` does not store a `ICollection<Person> SecondaryPersons` there is no bidirectionalness here), which means you must enforce the constraints yourself, but is this a big issue? I guess this has a circular reference but... so does your domain class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
public class PersonMap : ClassMap<Person>
{
  public PersonMap()
  {
    Table("Persons");
    Id(x =>x.Id, "PersonId").GeneratedBy.Identity();
    References(x => x.User).Column("UserId").Cascade.All();
    Map(x => x.FirstName, "FirstName");
    Map(x => x.LastName, "LastName");
    Map(x => x.Address, "Address");
    Map(x => x.Phone, "Phone");
    // More property maps
  }
}

public class UserMap : ClassMap<User>
{
  public UserMap()
  {
    Id(x => x.Id, "UserId").GeneratedBy.Identity();
    Map(x => x.Username, "Username");
    Map(x => x.Password, "Password");
    References<Person>(x => x.PrimaryPerson).ForeignKey("PrimaryPersonId").Cascade.All();
  }
}
```

This is assuming your Ids are autonumber and that when you update a User, you also want your PrimaryPerson to be updated along with it.  Change the Cascade.All() to Cascade.None() if that isn't the case.  Just be sure that when you do, you update the PrimaryPerson manually or you'll get a "object references an unsaved transient instance" upon SubmitChanges() if you don't.

Comment: Exactly what we needed.  Works perfectly.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my comment on your question, I think the mapping would be something along the lines of:

```
public class PersonMap : ClassMap<Person>
{
    public PersonMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id)...
        ...
        References(x => x.User).Inverse(); // User references Person
    }
}

public class UserMap : ClassMap<User>
{
    public UserMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id)...
        ...
        References(x => x.PrimaryPerson).Column("PrimaryPersonId")...
        HasMany(x => x.People).KeyColumn("UserId").Inverse(); // UserId is on the Person
    }
}
```

---

Edit: Added Table Structure.

```
[User]
UserId
... -- Other Columns
PrimaryPersonId  -- FK to PersonId in Person table

[Person]
PersonId
... -- Other Columns
UserId -- FK to UserId in User Table for user has many Persons.
```

Comment: I assume you're referring to HasMany(x => x.People).KeyColumn("UserId").Inverse(); ? This is a collection of persons (un-related to primary). I'll update my answer with the table structure so it makes sense.

Comment: Thanks, but what I mean is that there is no such thing as References(x => x.User).Inverse(); nor is there References(x => x.User).Column("UserId").Inverse();

Comment: Hey, I assumed the schema mapping, can you update your question with your schema?